# Adjust table automatically

Tags: css, html-table

I've a table containing one row of radio options and another with two paragraphs out of which only one will be displayed and another hidden based on value selected by user in radio options.

The issue is, those two paragraphs are of different content length making one paragraph consuming more space in table. When user selects the option to display bigger paragraph, the table expands automatically to fit bigger content. But again later if user selects a radio option to display small paragraph, it does not shrink it back which should shrink to fit a small paragraph.

Is there any to handle it in CSS?

Comment: Possibly, but we need to see your markup and CSS of what you've already tried...

Answer (score 0):

You could try add this css as below, if not work, could you please paste your codes here for further investigation? hope this helps.
**table-layout:fixed;**